# xrdp localhost only to enable access only through ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, tunnel

I am having several brute force attacks in my server through SSH and XRDP, so im using `sshguard` to avoid them through ssh, but i can't find a way to protect the RDP access. I found that the best way to so it is just enabling rdp access through ssh tunnel and then sshguard could protect both. Also having just 1 open port to internet make me more safe.

The problem is i don't know how to configure my server to make XRDP only accessible in local through ssh tunnel.

Could you please help me about this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you've got your server locked down behind or with a firewall.  If so, just close the XRDP ports (3389, IIRC) with `iptables` or similar.  The the only access will be allowed from the localhost, which you are presumably already doing with your `ssh` tunnel (e.g. `ssh -L 4489:localhost:3389 server`).

Also, while not strictly more secure, you can make your ssh server less visible by running it on (or forward externally from) a different port.  I find I end up with many fewer drive-by hacking attempts, and those that do come in, I pay more attention to because clearly they are more energized to have bothered to find my alternative port and then try to get in via the right protocol.